# what is format to specify connectSpec for alljoyn_busattachment_connect on windows machine

Tags: windows, iot, alljoyn

Alljoyn SDK documentation for **alljoyn_busattachment_connect** @ https://allseenalliance.org/docs/api/c/_bus_attachment_8h.html#aeb22a38b231141d0d59b7b907379661f
says we can provide connectSpec to this method. Can you please let me know some real example how can i format machine IP address & PORT to form a correct connectSpec.

I just want to establish connection via explicit IP & PORT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some connectSpec examples from the AllJoyn source code.

In alljoyn_core/samples/windows/PhotoChat/AllJoynBusLib/AllJoynConnection.cpp, we see an example of a connectSpec using the tcp transport...

```
"tcp:addr=127.0.0.1,port=9955"
```

In alljoyn_core/router/test/bbdaemon.cc, we see an example of a connectSpec that includes the unix, tcp, and udp transports...

```
"unix:abstract=alljoyn;tcp:;udp:u4addr=0.0.0.0,u4port=9955"
```